# change font size globally not work

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to change font size globally for full document. below code not work:

```
\documentclass[24pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

It says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [24pt].
```

Comment: The standard classes do not provide an option `24pt`. If you really need such a large text font size, you should either use another class like `memoir` or `scrartcl` or use a package like `scrextend` or `fontsize`. But note, that in most cases you would also need a scalable font, e.g., using `\usepackage{lmoderm}` or LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX.